# Point consideration during circuit solving

Tags: electric-circuits

Why are the points *A*and *C* similar ?
Similar is the case of *B* and *D* ...

I mean , during circuit solving , the point *C* is taken as *A* ... and *D* as *B* ...?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no resistance between C and A, D and B, they are basically the same point.

Also, if you pick any starting point and any ending point the total resistance you'll have to pass through will be the same even if you switched out C for A, or D for B. For ex, to get from A to D would require the same work as to get from A to B. You'll have no way of choosing which point to go to!

I always like to think of water as an analogy. Between A and B is a hill so water will need to do work to flow to B. But when the water gets to B there's no hill separating B and D so the water inadvertently also goes to D. B and D would create one water pool.