# The equivalent resistance of the networks shown is

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

I solved the by taking resistance at the right side as in series but got ans as 5R/13 but  the  is 5R/11

Comment: Hi Meezan and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Consider the end of lines ,without resistance , as same points and redraw the circuit ...

Comment: I just dont get it what u said nehal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I talked about considering the end points of the wires same , as in case of **a** , **b** and **c** ... The rest I leave for you ....

You can also look up here ...[Point consideration during circuit solving](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/390932/point-consideration-during-circuit-solving)